# Lengthy operation at the start of an Android application

Tags: android

I'm writing an application for Android, which should get some data from the server as soon as it launches.

Between the start of the application and the response from the server (or timeout, if the server is down), the application should display a "waiting" animation.

Thereafter, the normal panel should be shown (if the server responded) or an error dialog box be displayed (if the server didn't respond).

What is the correct place to put this logic into?

`MainActivity.onCreate` or some other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the data loaded only when the app starts for the first time, `onCreate()` is the right place. if you want to re-loaded every time the app comes into focus (i.e., the foreground), then `onResume()` is the right place. take a look at documentation on the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for details.

you'll want to take a look into [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html)+[`AsyncTaskLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) to understand the right pattern for doing something in the background then updating the UI with the result.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeffrey suggested at first you have to determine when you want to connect to the server? Depending on this you should connect to server in `onCreate` or `onResume`.

Now you must remember one thing that you can't do heavey tasks in your manin GUI thread. Else there is a good chance of `ANR`. So you have to implement this feature in a different thread. For this you can use different `Thread`, `Handler` or `AsyncTask`. You can find a nice doc [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

I think it is a suitable situation to use AsyncTask. So here is an example with AsyncTask

```
private class ServerCommunication extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // show the connecting screen
        // or you can do this before calling asyncTask
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // communicate with server
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // show the second screeen
    }

}
```

and call it using

```
    ServerCommunication pcd = new ServerCommunication();
    pcd.execute();
```

This is just for suggesting the structure. You can definitely use neccessary paramenters or other method also.